# Can't upload to google cloud or firebase storage bucket from nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I have been trying to upload some images to my firebase storage bucket . 
I have followed this official docs :-

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start

and https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/latest/storage/bucket

I am able to see the files which are already present in the bucket (these files were stored there using an android app)

But I'm not able to upload local files from nodejs's admin.storage module .

Here is the code :

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://myprojectid.firebaseio.com/" , 
  storageBucket : "myprojectid.appspot.com/"
});

bucket = admin.storage().bucket() ; 
bucket.upload('./mylocalfile.jpg' , (err , file , response)=>{
console.log(err) ; //always gives me err
console.log(file) ; //gives undefined
}) ;
```

But `bucket.getFiles().then(objects=>console.log(objects)) ;` works perfectly and prints the files present in the root .

How to fix this ?

Here is the `error` it prints when console logging `err` :

```
{ ApiError: Not Found
    at Object.parseHttpRespMessage (C:\Users\Natesh\Desktop\AttentionPlease_backend\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@google-cloud\common\src\util.js:156:33)
    at Object.handleResp (C:\Users\Natesh\Desktop\AttentionPlease_backend\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@google-cloud\common\src\util.js:131:18)
    at C:\Users\Natesh\Desktop\AttentionPlease_backend\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@google-cloud\common\src\util.js:465:12
    at Request.onResponse [as _callback] (C:\Users\Natesh\Desktop\AttentionPlease_backend\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\retry-request\index.js:179:7)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Natesh\Desktop\AttentionPlease_backend\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Natesh\Desktop\AttentionPlease_backend\functions\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\request\request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
  code: 404,
  errors: [],
  response:
   IncomingMessage {
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: true,
        endEmitted: true,
        reading: false,
        sync: true,
        needReadable: false,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain:
      Domain {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        members: [] },
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function],
        error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 4,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     socket:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        npnProtocol: false,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'www.googleapis.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 4047,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [Object],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: null,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleStart: 1307656 },
     connection:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        npnProtocol: false,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'www.googleapis.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 4047,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [Object],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: null,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleStart: 1307656 },
     httpVersionMajor: 1,
     httpVersionMinor: 1,
     httpVersion: '1.1',
     complete: true,
     headers:
      { 'x-guploader-uploadid': 'AEnB2UqADzuHb4O7UjdBAui1cDWeLNO4s0YuT2krCPoYIHaUrYPjXRH8rBU0mcSi9n7sie11PhALTN2vOKkhykW0apqTbrNB9Q',
        vary: 'Origin, X-Origin',
        'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        'content-length': '9',
        date: 'Sat, 17 Mar 2018 13:24:19 GMT',
        server: 'UploadServer',
        'alt-svc': 'hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,35"' },
     rawHeaders:
      [ 'X-GUploader-UploadID',
        'AEnB2UqADzuHb4O7UjdBAui1cDWeLNO4s0YuT2krCPoYIHaUrYPjXRH8rBU0mcSi9n7sie11PhALTN2vOKkhykW0apqTbrNB9Q',
        'Vary',
        'Origin',
        'Vary',
        'X-Origin',
        'Content-Type',
        'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        'Content-Length',
        '9',
        'Date',
        'Sat, 17 Mar 2018 13:24:19 GMT',
        'Server',
        'UploadServer',
        'Alt-Svc',
        'hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,35"' ],
     trailers: {},
     rawTrailers: [],
     upgrade: false,
     url: '',
     method: null,
     statusCode: 404,
     statusMessage: 'Not Found',
     client:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        npnProtocol: false,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'www.googleapis.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 4047,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: [Object],
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: null,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleStart: 1307656 },
     _consuming: true,
     _dumped: false,
     req:
      ClientRequest {
        domain: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: true,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: [Object],
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /upload/storage/v1/b/myprojectid.appspot.com//o?uploadType=multipart&name=profile HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: gcloud-node-storage/1.4.0\r\nx-goog-api-client: gl-node/6.11.5 gccl/1.4.0\r\nAuthorization: Bearer ya29.c.<PLACEHOLDER_FOR_SOME_LONG_AUTH_ID>\r\nhost: www.googleapis.com\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate\r\ntransfer-encoding: chunked\r\ncontent-type: multipart/related; boundary=6e012a90-2cb1-4c46-9de5-bb75cb5949ea\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/upload/storage/v1/b/myprojectid.appspot.com//o?uploadType=multipart&name=profile',
        _ended: true,
        parser: null,
        timeoutCb: null,
        res: [Circular] },
     request:
      Request {
        domain: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        timeout: 60000,
        gzip: true,
        forever: true,
        pool: [Object],
        method: 'POST',
        uri: [Object],
        headers: [Object],
        callback: [Function],
        readable: true,
        writable: true,
        explicitMethod: true,
        _qs: [Object],
        _auth: [Object],
        _oauth: [Object],
        _multipart: [Object],
        _redirect: [Object],
        _tunnel: [Object],
        setHeader: [Function],
        hasHeader: [Function],
        getHeader: [Function],
        removeHeader: [Function],
        localAddress: undefined,
        dests: [],
        __isRequestRequest: true,
        _callback: [Function: onResponse],
        proxy: null,
        tunnel: true,
        setHost: true,
        originalCookieHeader: undefined,
        _disableCookies: true,
        _jar: undefined,
        port: 443,
        host: 'www.googleapis.com',
        url: [Object],
        path: '/upload/storage/v1/b/myprojectid.appspot.com//o?uploadType=multipart&name=profile',
        httpModule: [Object],
        agentClass: [Object],
        agentOptions: [Object],
        agent: [Object],
        src: [Object],
        _started: true,
        href: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myprojectid.appspot.com//o?uploadType=multipart&name=profile',
        req: [Object],
        ntick: true,
        response: [Circular],
        originalHost: 'www.googleapis.com',
        originalHostHeaderName: 'host',
        responseContent: [Circular],
        _destdata: true,
        _ended: true,
        _callbackCalled: true },
     toJSON: [Function: responseToJSON],
     caseless: Caseless { dict: [Object] },
     read: [Function],
     body: 'Not Found' },
  message: 'Not Found' }
```

Comment: I'm not clear.  Are you saying that `bucket.upload()` gives you this error, but the file appears in the storage bucket anyway?

Comment: Try dropping the `/` at the end of the `storageBucket` option. Also make sure you have write permissions for the bucket.

Comment: the file is not uploaded to the storage . i have checked . And I also don't have any write restrictions too

Comment: Did you try after changing `storageBucket : "myprojectid.appspot.com/"` to `storageBucket : "myprojectid.appspot.com"` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that @tarun . That won't even fetch the present files in the bucket.

Comment: Please join this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167162/discussion-cant-upload-to-google-cloud-or-firebase-storage-bucket-from-nodejs) room

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the 'upload' function only receive path to local file or url, so it cause some complexity when implement uploading file REST api by cloud functions.
I'm guessing it shouldn't be a proper way to upload a file to cloud function server and upload a local file to cloud storage.

Here's what I accomplished to make upload endpoint to firebase (gcloud) storage using multer to get file from the request, then convert it to data and use save function to upload.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const multer  = require('multer');
const app = express();
const fileUpload = multer();

admin.initializeApp(.......);

/*
 * Upload File
 **/
app.post('/', fileUpload.single('file'), functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const file = req.file;
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
  const name = file.originalname;
  
  const bucketFile = bucket.file(name);

  bucketFile
    .save(new Buffer(file.buffer))
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        data: Object.assign({}, bucketFile.metadata, {
          downloadURL: `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${name}`,
        })
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        status: 'error',
        errors: err,
      });
    });
}));
```

Here's my POSTMAN screen for test.

[image]

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: its not working for me , i'm using express-fileupload module to access the file in the post request . Can u please show me if it works to upload local files too ?

Comment: local mean, a file in your computer? or a file on your server?

Comment: a file on the server . since i am running the nodejs server i meant that as the local file :\ . Anyway can u please add the post request parameters too. Still getting the API : not found error  ?